# Does Google Play Apps Testing work?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to test an android app.

I've uploaded an APK to the "Alpha" section, but the given link returns error 500:

"Share the following link with your testers: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/program".

The Beta version returns the same error.

Of course, my app is already published but only as Alpha version.

Does someone have a workaround for this? Or I must publish a working version on Google Play first? Or there is another problem of the "Error 500" for testing link?

Comment: i am getting 404 all the time, were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From Google's Developer Help Center (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en):

"It may take up to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to become active."

Also, standard Android package names are in the form of `com.[developer].[program]`; not `com.[program]` -- that would cause issues.

Comment: That link still not work. I recreated Google Play project from scratch with another package name (it was com.package, now it have com.package.client name) and test link now works without error 500.