# Google play alpha/beta testing url is not working

Tags: android

I've uploaded Alpha testing APK file on Google Play and published. Alpha testing member signed up Google Circle and clicked testing URL. https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.company.example. Like this one.

However, it won't show up on Google Play. It cannot find the application. Like this.

```
We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I waited 24 hours to get published, but it is same. I found out that this guy had same issue like me. [Is Google Play Apps Testing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836940/is-google-play-apps-testing-work) But, I do not want to change the package name of application.

Is there someone who knows how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: The link only works if you are a part of the Google Group you setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to wait for 24 hours to be appeared on Google Play.

Comment: Yes, please wait for atleast 24 hours. The url will work for sure.

Comment: I'm waiting for more than 24 hours (About 32 hours), Is it a normal range of time to wait before the app is actually published on Alpha testing?

Comment: @user2235615 try to use closed beta. It takes less than 2~3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it take only 2~3 hours to be published. Try close beta, and make sure your account is on the beta user list. Also, you have to make sure that you logged with beta google account on Google Play app.